# JhiEventManager multiple subscriptions

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

Will **JhiEventManager** allow multiple subscriptions or should I have dedicated subscription for every single event? Will *destroy*() method of **JhiEventManager** take care of multiple subscriptions as well?

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  eventSubscriber?: Subscription;
 
  constructor(protected eventManager: JhiEventManager) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registerChanges();
  }

  registerChanges(): void {
    this.eventSubscriber = this.eventManager.subscribe('first EntityListModification', () => this.someaction());
    // ??? chain this to the same eventSubscriber ???
    this.eventManager.subscribe('secondEntityListModification', () => this.someaction());
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.eventSubscriber) {
      this.eventManager.destroy(this.eventSubscriber);
    }
  }
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read JhiEventManager code? It's very short so I guess that it does not do what you want and honestly its destroy() function has little value.

Comment: Thanks, it seems it is possible doing so unless destroy() function won't call unsubscribe anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [current implementation of JhiEventManager](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/master/src/service/event-manager.service.ts) it is possible to handle stuff in one **Subscription**:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription?: Subscription;

  constructor(protected eventManager: JhiEventManager) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registerAllEvents();
  }

  registerAllEvents(): void {
    this.subscription = this.eventManager.subscribe('event1', () => this.loadAll());
    this.subscription.add(this.eventManager.subscribe('event2', () => this.loadAll()));
    this.subscription.add(this.eventManager.subscribe('event3', () => this.loadAll()));
    ...
    this.subscription.add(this.eventManager.subscribe('eventN', () => this.loadAll()));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.eventManager.destroy(this.subscription);
    }
  }
```

Please refer to https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription for detailed description:

> call to an unsubscribe() of one Subscription may unsubscribe multiple
> Subscriptions. You can do this by "adding" one subscription into
> another:

Comment: Great. I realize I did not understand your requirements :)